# Date difference over consecutive rows filtered to one instance of consecutive values using LEAD function

Tags: sql-server-2014, data-partitioning, lead

Basically the result i need is price change ranges for each item, i need to extract an item price and the date of the transaction with an end date set to the next time that item price is changed.

Given this [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/293d1/3)

```
create table myTable(id int, Price decimal(10,6), StartDate datetime)
insert into myTable
select 1, 92.576842, '2018-04-06 23:00:00.000' union all
select 1, 92.700000, '2018-04-12 21:39:00.000' union all
select 1, 92.700000, '2018-04-26 00:01:00.000' union all
select 1, 92.700000, '2018-06-04 23:20:00.000' union all
select 1, 116.700000, '2018-07-04 21:38:00.000' union all
select 1, 116.700000, '2018-08-01 22:31:31.000' union all
select 1, 118.610597, '2018-08-13 23:34:22.000' union all
select 1, 116.700000, '2018-09-05 23:52:28.000'
```

And this query

```
select id, Price, StartDate, LEAD(StartDate) over (partition by id order by id, StartDate) endDate
from myTable
order by id, StartDate
```

Query Results:

```
id  Price       StartDate               endDate
1   92.576842   2018-04-06 23:00:00.000 2018-04-12 21:39:00.000
1   92.700000   2018-04-12 21:39:00.000 2018-04-26 00:01:00.000
1   92.700000   2018-04-26 00:01:00.000 2018-06-04 23:20:00.000
1   92.700000   2018-06-04 23:20:00.000 2018-07-04 21:38:00.000
1   116.700000  2018-07-04 21:38:00.000 2018-08-01 22:31:31.000
1   116.700000  2018-08-01 22:31:31.000 2018-08-13 23:34:22.000
1   118.610597  2018-08-13 23:34:22.000 2018-09-05 23:52:28.000
1   116.700000  2018-09-05 23:52:28.000 NULL
```

how to get only the earliest date for consecutive `Price` instance

the result should be as below - note that last row is a duplicated `Price` yet it is required

```
id  Price       StartDate               EndDate
1   92.576842   2018-04-06 23:00:00.000 2018-04-12 21:39:00.000
1   92.700000   2018-04-12 21:39:00.000 2018-07-04 21:38:00.000
1   116.700000  2018-07-04 21:38:00.000 2018-08-13 23:34:22.000
1   118.610597  2018-08-13 23:34:22.000 2018-09-05 23:52:28.000
1   116.700000  2018-09-05 23:52:28.000 NULL
```

Comment: sticking to LEAD function is recommendation not requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an approach for "islands" that employs 2 row_number() calculations that give all rows in an "island" a shared id, then it is possible to group by that id:

```
select
    id, Price, group_id, min(StartDate) StartDate, max(enddate) enddate
from (
        select id, Price, StartDate
            , LEAD(StartDate,1,DATEADD(YEAR,1,StartDate)) over (partition by id order by id,StartDate) endDate
            , row_number() over(partition by id order by StartDate ASC) 
              - row_number() over(partition by id, price order by StartDate ASC) AS group_id
        from myTable
      ) d
group by
    id, Price, group_id
order by
    id,StartDate
;

| id |      Price | group_id |            StartDate |              enddate |
|----|------------|----------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 |  92.576842 |        0 | 2018-04-06T23:00:00Z | 2018-04-12T21:39:00Z |
|  1 |       92.7 |        1 | 2018-04-12T21:39:00Z | 2018-07-04T21:38:00Z |
|  1 |      116.7 |        4 | 2018-07-04T21:38:00Z | 2018-08-13T23:34:22Z |
|  1 | 118.610597 |        6 | 2018-08-13T23:34:22Z | 2018-09-05T23:52:28Z |
|  1 |      116.7 |        5 | 2018-09-05T23:52:28Z | 2019-09-05T23:52:28Z |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/293d1/6

If you want NULL as the last enddate, change the lead() so it does not supply a default value

```
LEAD(StartDate,1)) over (partition by id order by id,StartDate) endDate
```

Comment: while ranges are correct, still the last record when price went back to previous value of 116.70 gets grouped and not displayed.

Comment: sorry, revised answer for "islands" now provided.

Comment: thanks pal. flawless. also the group_id helped in further queries